# eclipse : How can I change method signature with change return value too

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I want to change `return type` name in a method in `abstract` class by one step, then update this change to all super classes.

I do that by right-click-->refactor-->change method signature, it works fine but return value didn't change. So I forced to change all super classes manually again but this waste of my time.

For example, change this line:

```
public abstract String getX();
```

To>>

```
public abstract int getX();
```

The result return in super classes not change. The result:

```
@Override
public int getX() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Any Advice?

Comment: Return type is not included in method's signature. If you need another return type - create a new method

Comment: I think this is missing in eclipse IDE. because if you have a many of super classes, then you need something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Change Method Signature](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm) (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) to change also return type

> Change Method Signature    Changes parameter names, parameter types, parameter order and updates all references to the corresponding method. Additionally, parameters and thrown exceptions can be removed or added and method **return type and method visibility can be changed**.

[Screnshot from DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/java-eclipse-code-refactoring-shortcuts-and-tips):
[image]